# How to add an external SP (Service Provider) in Mujina IDP (IDentity Provider)?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

[Mujina-IDP](https://github.com/OpenConext/Mujina/tree/master/mujina-idp) is a developers-oriented testing tool implementing a SAML2 IDentity Provider.
Out-of-the-box, it works great with the bundled test Service Provider [Mujina-SP](https://github.com/OpenConext/Mujina/tree/master/mujina-sp).

**QUESTION**: How to make Mujina-IDP handle authentication requests from another SP?

I could not find in the [Mujina documentation](https://github.com/OpenConext/Mujina/blob/master/README.md) nor by looking at the configuration files.
Is there a setting, or a REST call to perform, or do I have to modify the source code?
Or does it just work with any SP, without having to configure anything?

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya: Unfortunately not. So I used OpenAM instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without configuration SP not connected with mujina IDP.
You should provide public and private certificate of your SP in IDP application.yml file like -
idp:
base_url : localhost
private_key : base64 key
.
.
.
Idp1:
base_url : localhost
private_key : base64 key
.
.
.
.

IDP for one external sp and IDP1 having another sp configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a mock IdP, Mujuna will authenticate to any SP that sends an authentication request to it. So there's no need to configure the SP you want to use in Mujina.

You just need to configure your SP to use Mujina's endpoint/certificate to authenticate to.